# Avoiding binding in Render while maintaining context from Parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have (TableHeader component) table headers being rendered with `onClick` handlers which, when fired, capture the value of the header and set state in the Parent component (Parent is a Table component, child is TableHeader).

I want to avoid binding the onClick function within TableHeader's render method while still maintaining access to the Parent component's context. Currently what I have:

```
render() {
  return (
  ...
    <tr>
      {columns.map(col => <th key={col} onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(null, col)} {...hoverHandlers}>{col}</th>)}
    </tr>
  )
}
```

The function being passed to each th is just taking the value of the column and sorting accordingly.

In the parent component's constructor, that function is bound:

```
this.sortColumns = this.sortColumns.bind(this);
```

Then passed:

```
<TableHeader onClick={this.sortColumns} />
```

Comment: What is "col"? I am trying to figure out if there is some reason why you need to use render() to bind to "col," but I don't know enough about it to say. Could you show the code that assigns it?

Comment: @Jose, we would need some more information here.Can you post the some more snippets of your code?

Comment: @ErikHermansen Sorry, col is coming from an array being mapped. Got chopped off when pasting. Will update.

Comment: I think you shouldn't need to bind onClick() in render. Are you able to change the sortColumns function so that it takes "col" as a parameter to it? If so, then there is just the issue of calling it correctly, which I can show pretty easily how to do.

Comment: @ErikHermansen I just realized what was happening. So `sortColumns` is taking a col argument, but when modified to take another argument (and logged), the col value appears as the second argument. While I think it's easy to keep it this way, I'd like to restrict it to just the one argument - if that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of using bind() to pass around different contexts. It's correct, but just a little hard to follow. So my answer below is suggesting you pass "col" as a param--easy to see what's going on. But if that doesn't work for you, maybe explain why not, and maybe you'll get a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `sortColumns()` to take the `col` variable as a parameter. And then update `render()` to pass the variable.

```
render() {
  return (
   ...
   <tr>
     {columns.map(col => <th key={col} 
        onClick={function() { this.props.onClick(col) } } 
        {...hoverHandlers}>{col}</th>)}
   </tr>
   )
}
```